# Android - load data from database once

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I write an application in which the user can add events to track some activities. The data is saved in `Room` database. The application has a single activity and use fragments.

My current implementation is as follow: I have a `LiveData` which has an interface to get "all entries", "all entries of type X" and "entry with specific ID". Then, when each fragment is loaded, it retrieve the data it needs from the db. Sometimes it take more time and some time less but it can be annoying to wait for the data to load.

I thought about keeping the data in the memory all the time and every time the user updates something I would keep it in the memory and in a background thread save it to the db.

Now to the problem:

- The simplest solution would be to load all of the data when the app starts. The user would see some kind of a loading screen. Then, every call to "get data" would return immediately. The problem - this loading time can be super long and can be done in chunks while the user starts using the app. Like a loading feed in facebook.
- The second solution would be to load "on-demand" - load at the first time something is requested. Because of it, everywhere in my app I would have an observer like pattern, live in `LiveData`, to notify the data is ready. Yet, I would like it to load the data only if it is not loaded.

What I'm searching for is something like `LiveData` but which loads the data once and then everyone and not every time - for example a function which returns `LiveData` which loads the data from the db.

Further more, I think my design probably miss something which is common in Android and I would love to hear what it is. What is the right way to implement such application?

Answer (score 0):

I think a repository layer can be helpful in this case.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide
[image]

Below is the sample code assuming you are using Kotlin, courotin do not need to monitor changes in database's data.

The repository can be a singleton to serve as a simple memory cache.

```
object Repository {
//private mutable liveData for internal usage
private val _data = MutableLiveData<String> ()

//public liveData exposed to fragment/viewModel
val data: LiveData<String>
get() {
    if (_data.value==null)
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatcher.IO){
            fetchData()
        }
    return _data
}

suspend fun fetchData(){
    //get data from Dao
    val dataFromDatabase = "123"
    //assign the data retrieved to the liveData
    _data.value = dataFromDatabase
}
}
```

you can call fetchData in loading screen and access data in other fragment that required the data.

If you need to monitor the data changes in database, `Room` can actually return a LiveData/Flow which update the value whenever data changes. https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#8, this is a example showing that.